# How to get an element inside of an array in a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

Code below outputs an array of users stored in Firestore db. Each document have the same id of a user.

```
  const [user] = useAuthState(auth);
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState([]);

  const usersDB = collection(firestore, "Users");

  const getUsers = async () => {
    const data = await getDocs(usersDB);
    setUserData(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getUsers();
  }, []);
```

I want to access the document with same id as logged in user and check if isAdmin field is true or false using useAuthState to get user uid. How should I write the code for this?

Comment: useEffect has a dependency array. For instance if you do `useEffect(fn, [user]);` then `fn` gets called whenever `user` changes. In fn, check if user exists and read their isAdmin

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks for this, but I'm not quite sure what it does exactly. I want it to do two things. First access the document with same id as logged in user uid and then get a specific field that is isAdmin boolean.

Comment: Once the user authenticates, `user` will change. This will trigger the function you pass to `useEffect(fn, [user]);`. Inside this function you can now read the user id, then query the DB and set userData. Here's also where you can check the admin flag

Comment: Understood, but I'm fairly new to this so to write it out as you explain is kinda a big deal for me. Can you give a full example if possible?

Comment: Absolutely not, sorry. I was new to this five years ago, and I clawed my way through it alone (just React I mean, learning JS took even longer)

Comment: Well. Thanks anyways

Comment: Have you tried what ChrisG explained to you?

Comment: @ChristianPaulAndaya Yes, the structure of it I understand it's more the syntaxs that are a problem so not quite there yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code you are using `getDocs` instead of `getDoc`.

Here's a sample code using useEffect and checking boolean isAdmin.

```
const [userData, setUserData] = useState([]);
    const email = "test@xyz.com";
    const password = "123Addw1113#";

    const getUsers = async () => {
        signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
            .then((userCredential) => {
                const user = userCredential.user;

                setDoc(doc(db, "<collection>", user.uid), {
                    someField: "<data>",
                })
                    .then(async () => {
                        const docRef = doc(db, "<collection>", user.uid);
                        const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
                        if (docSnap.exists() && docSnap.data().isAdmin === true) {
                            setUserData(docSnap.data());
                            console.log("isAdmin is True");
                          } else if (docSnap.exists() && docSnap.data().isAdmin === false) {
                            console.log("isAdmin is False");
                          } else {
                            console.log("No such document!");
                          }
                    });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error)
            });
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        getUsers();
    }, []);
```

Comment: Thank you so much this worked. I had to work on another project since I couldn't solve this.